# Trouble in populating the drop down list in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

```
^Q::
ar := ["A|B"]
lst := ar[0]
Gui, Add, DropDownList, var, %lst%
Gui, Show
return
```

This doesn't fill the dropdown list. It's empty. But initializing `lst := "A|B"`  works correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AHKs arrays are 1-based, not 0-based.
So `lst := ar[1]` is going to work.